# Can't send mail using smtp.office365.com

Tags: .net, outlook, smtp, web-config, office365

Gmail's SMTP service is able to send emails:

```
<add key="infoMail" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpMail" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpPassword" value="pass" />
<add key="infoMail2" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpMail2" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpPassword2" value="pass" />
<add key="enableSSL" value="true" />
<add key="smtpHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<add key="smtpPort" value="587" />
```

Microsoft's SMTP service doesn't. It used to work - since it stopped working a while ago I changed to Gmail, but now I need to use Microsoft again. Why doesn't Microsoft's SMTP service work?

```
<add key="infoMail" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpMail" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpPassword" value="pass" />
<add key="infoMail2" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpMail2" value="example@example.com" />
<add key="smtpPassword2" value="pass" />
<add key="enableSSL" value="true" />
<add key="smtpHost" value="smtp.office365.com" />
<add key="smtpPort" value="587" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the smtpHost still valid, btw, Office 365 are using STARTTLS but not SSL/TLS, please take note:

Server/smart host:smtp.office365.com
Port:Port 587 (recommended) or port 25
TLS/StartTLS: Enabled
Username/email address and password: Enter the sign-in credentials of the hosted mailbox being used